# How to pass http referer value to Social Authentication Filter

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social

I want to navigate back to same screen from where Facebook login has initiated. I am using [SocialAuthenticationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/social/security/SocialAuthenticationFilter.html) to integrate Spring Social.

If I pass values for postLoginUrl and alwaysUsePostLoginUrl as true then it is redirecting correctly to postLoginUrl as mentioned.After removing them Facebook is redirecting to application context URL as mentioned in Facebook console.

My requirement is redirect to the page from which the authentication flow has started. So do I need to extend Authentication filter or do I need to use any other property to redirect to referer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no direct way to mention redirect URL dynamically. So I navigated all the responses from Facebook to a single URI, where in I handled to divert calls to specific pages of my interest.